# background image css check using capybara

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a system test that visits the login page and I want to check for a css background image:

**CSS**

```
.public {
  background-image: url("bg-public.png");
}
```

**Spec**

```
visit login_path
expect(page).to have_css('.public', style: { 'background-image' => 'bg-public.png' })
```

output

```
 expected to find visible css ".public" with styles {"background-image"=>"bg-public.png"} but there were no matches.
```

When I look in the inspector I can see:

```
.public {
background-image: url(/assets/bg-public-02eb392a12e5cf1a0359331517b16615a91f5ee93ca225a5e7498bf129edc3d5.png)
```

adding this url to the test returns the same result:

```
 expected to find visible css ".public" with styles {"background-image"=>"url(/assets/bg-public-02eb392a12e5cf1a0359331517b16615a91f5ee93ca225a5e7498bf129edc3d5.png))"} but there were no matches.
```

or

```
expected to find visible css ".public" with styles {"background-image"=>"url(bg-public-02eb392a12e5cf1a0359331517b16615a91f5ee93ca225a5e7498bf129edc3d5.png))"} but there were no matches

expected to find visible css ".public" with styles {"background-image"=>"bg-public-02eb392a12e5cf1a0359331517b16615a91f5ee93ca225a5e7498bf129edc3d5.png"} but there were no matches.
```

Answer (score 0):

The asset name is potentially different in the dev, stage, and production environments.  If you're running with a real browser for testing try pausing the test and inspecting what the actual url is.  A more flexible option is to use a regexp for the match

```
expect(page).to have_css('.public', style: { 'background-image' => /bg-public.*\.png/' })
```

Note, that if you have a reference to the element and you query for the style - like

```
el = page.find('.public', style: { 'background-image' => /bg-public.*\.png/' })
puts el.style('background-image')
```

you'll probably see that from the browsers perspective once parsed the value is actually a fully qualified domain name like

```
url("http://127.0.0.1:62749/asset/bg-public-02eb392a12e5cf1a0359331517b16615a91f5ee93ca225a5e7498bf129edc3d5.png)
```

which you could attempt to use, but you'll need to get the port from the server, etc -- just using a regexp will be far simpler.